# Imagick and GridFS

Tags: php, image, mongodb, imagick, gridfs

I have images stored in GridFS for MongoDB. When I pull the image out, I want to resize it and then store it back into the database. I tried this:

```
$image = $grid_collection ->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoID($id)));
new Imagick($image -> getBytes());
```

But that throws an error in Imagick. Now I can write it out to file temporarily to disk and have Imagick read the file, but that seems the long way around. Any suggestions on a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
$data = $grid->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoID($id)));

$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImageBlob($data->getBytes());
```

Comment: After having applied some feature on $img (rotation or whatever), how do you store it back in Mongo ?

Answer (score -1):

You can't store images in a specefication.  What do you mean by

> I have images stored in GridFS

[GridFS is a spec.](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS)

Comment: GridFS is also the name of the API which uses the GridFS specs.